# Assigning np.nans to rows of a Pandas column using a query

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, assign

I want to assign NaNs to the rows of a column in a Pandas dataframe when some conditions are met.

For a reproducible example here are some data:

```
'{"Price":{"1581292800000":21.6800003052,"1581379200000":21.6000003815,"1581465600000":21.6000003815,"1581552000000":21.6000003815,"1581638400000":22.1599998474,"1581984000000":21.9300003052,"1582070400000":22.0,"1582156800000":21.9300003052,"1582243200000":22.0200004578,"1582502400000":21.8899993896,"1582588800000":21.9699993134,"1582675200000":21.9599990845,"1582761600000":21.8500003815,"1582848000000":22.0300006866,"1583107200000":21.8600006104,"1583193600000":21.8199996948,"1583280000000":21.9699993134,"1583366400000":22.0100002289,"1583452800000":21.7399997711,"1583712000000":21.5100002289},"Target10":{"1581292800000":22.9500007629,"1581379200000":23.1000003815,"1581465600000":23.0300006866,"1581552000000":22.7999992371,"1581638400000":22.9599990845,"1581984000000":22.5799999237,"1582070400000":22.3799991608,"1582156800000":22.25,"1582243200000":22.4699993134,"1582502400000":22.2900009155,"1582588800000":22.3248996735,"1582675200000":null,"1582761600000":null,"1582848000000":null,"1583107200000":null,"1583193600000":null,"1583280000000":null,"1583366400000":null,"1583452800000":null,"1583712000000":null}}'
```

In this particular toy example, I want to assign NaNs to the column 'Price' when the column 'Target10' has NaNs.  (in the general case the condition may be more complex)

This line of code achieves that specific objective:

```
toy_data.Price.where(toy_data.Target10.notnull(), toy_data.Target10)
```

However when I attempt to use a query and assign NaNs to the targeted column I fail:

```
toy_data.query('Target10.isnull()', engine = 'python').Price = np.nan
```

The above line leaves `toy_data` intact.

Why is that and how I should use `query` to replace values in particular rows?

Comment: `query` is used for select, not for set values, I think not possible by `query`

Comment: `toy_data.loc[toy_data['Target10'].isna(), 'Price'] = np.nan`

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is -

```
import numpy as np 
toy_data['Price'] = np.where(toy_data['Target10'].isna(), np.nan, toy_data['Price'])
```